# Creating sign in for custom model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

There are lots of methods to realize user authentication in Django. And I used model form to create a form and sign up process. Now I really have no idea about signing in. I can't use built-in login, because there is no relation between my model (it's called `Account`) and django's built-in User model. I want to get some advice about the way. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def sign_up(request):
    context = {}
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "sign_up.html", context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    university_name = models.ForeignKey(
        University, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    isPhysicalAccount = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

`forms.py`:

```
lass SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exemple how to make your custom `Account`

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import ( PermissionsMixin, 
  _user_has_module_perms, _user_has_perm )

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
 username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=60)
 university_name = models.ForeignKey(
    University, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
 isPhysicalAccount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.username

 def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
        return True
    return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)

 def has_perms(self, perm_list, obj=None):
    return all(self.has_perm(perm, obj) for perm in perm_list)

 def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
        return True
    return _user_has_module_perms(self, app_label)


USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.Account'
```

Comment: now it says ```AttributeError: type object 'Account' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'``` and doesn't let me make migration or run server :(

Comment: Friend, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Extend django user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    university_name = models.ForeignKey(
        University, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    isPhysicalAccount = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        ordering = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

settings.py:

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.User'
```

to get user with this model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user_model = get_user_model()
user_model.objects.get(id=1)
```

sign up view with your logic:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def sign_up(request):
    context = {}
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "sign_up.html", context)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. The only thing that I don't understand is should I delete my Account model completely and leave only one User model as you said ?

Comment: Yes. You don’t need an extra request in the future to get account information.

Comment: I'm so sorry, man, what does ```django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user``` mean ?

Comment: maybe forgot migration?

Comment: check database table `django_migrations`.
here is all migrations, what you apply.

migration with new User model here too?

Comment: yes, there is. But only django's built in ```admin``` model in it.

Comment: Can you create a new database and add it to `settings.py`?
Problem still here?

Comment: i think, you should fix migrations and database scheme

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.